# How make correctely main thread on using sempanhores to sync Alamofire requests Swift4?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire

I'am using semaphores to sync my requests on AlamofireXMLRPC. So my function is:

```
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
for i in idsCloud {
            if !idsLocal.contains(i) {
                count += 1
                print("\n---->O ID: \(i) NÃO CONSTA NO BANCO LOCAL! <----\n")
                // se o id nao consta no banco local, deve inseri-lo
                OdooService.getProductByIdFromOdoo(id: i,successBlock: { (p) in
                    CoreDataHandler.saveProduct(p: p)
                    semaphore.signal()
                }, failureBlock: { (erro) in
                    print(erro)
                })

                semaphore.wait()
            }
    }


static func getProductByIdFromOdoo( id : Int, successBlock: @escaping (_ params : [String:Any]) -> Void, failureBlock: @escaping (_ params : String) -> Void) {
        if !checkOdooConn() {
            failureBlock("Falha na conexão com o Odoo")
            return
        }

        let options = ["fields": fieldsProducts] as [String:Any]
        let params = [OdooAuth.db,OdooAuth.uid,OdooAuth.password,"product.template","search_read",[[["id","=",id]]],options] as [Any]

        print("start request...")
        AlamofireXMLRPC.request(OdooAuth.host2, methodName: "execute_kw", parameters: params).responseXMLRPC(queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)) {
            (response: DataResponse<XMLRPCNode>) -> Void in
            switch response.result {
            case .success( _):
                let str = String(data: response.data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) as String!
                let options = AEXMLOptions()
                let pdict = strToDict(str: str!,options: options)
                successBlock(pdict.first!)
                break
            case .failure(let error):
                failureBlock(error.localizedDescription)
                break
            } // fim switch
        } // fim request

    }
```

On first iteraction of my "for i in idsCloud" I receive a strange message on console.

```
=================================================================
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication delegate]
PID: 30310, TID: 1868520, Thread name: (none), Queue name: com.apple.root.background-qos, QoS: 9
Backtrace:
4   OdooVendas                          0x00000001082d184e _T010OdooVendas15CoreDataHandlerC10getContext33_C78C41DC1F74DDA11E962327A9344CC5LLSo015NSManagedObjectG0CyFZ + 94
5   OdooVendas                          0x00000001082d1951 _T010OdooVendas15CoreDataHandlerC11saveProductys10DictionaryVySSypG1p_tFZ + 33
6   OdooVendas                          0x00000001082d588c _T010OdooVendas15CoreDataHandlerC12syncProductsyyFZys10DictionaryVySSypGcfU1_ + 60
7   OdooVendas                          0x00000001082d5aaa _T010OdooVendas15CoreDataHandlerC12syncProductsyyFZys10DictionaryVySSypGcfU1_TA + 58
8   OdooVendas                          0x00000001082f6cb1 _T010OdooVendas0A7ServiceC018getProductByIdFromA0ySi2id_ys10DictionaryVySSypGc12successBlockySSc07failureL0tFZy9Alamofire12DataResponseVy0N6XMLRPC10XMLRPCNodeVGcfU_ + 1697
9   OdooVendas                          0x00000001082f6f62 _T010OdooVendas0A7ServiceC018getProductByIdFromA0ySi2id_ys10DictionaryVySSypGc12successBlockySSc07failureL0tFZy9Alamofire12DataResponseVy0N6XMLRPC10XMLRPCNodeVGcfU_TA + 114
10  AlamofireXMLRPC                     0x00000001087e052d _T09Alamofire12DataResponseVy0A6XMLRPC10XMLRPCNodeVGIxx_AGIxi_TR + 173
11  AlamofireXMLRPC                     0x00000001087e1092 _T09Alamofire12DataResponseVy0A6XMLRPC10XMLRPCNodeVGIxx_AGIxi_TRTA + 66
12  Alamofire                           0x0000000108686819 _T09Alamofire11DataRequestC8responseACXDSo13DispatchQueueCSg5queue_x0D10SerializeryAA0B8ResponseVy16SerializedObjectQzGc17completionHandlertAA0biH8ProtocolRzlFyycfU_yycfU_ + 905
13  Alamofire                           0x000000010868f08e _T09Alamofire11DataRequestC8responseACXDSo13DispatchQueueCSg5queue_x0D10SerializeryAA0B8ResponseVy16SerializedObjectQzGc17completionHandlertAA0biH8ProtocolRzlFyycfU_yycfU_TA + 110
14  Alamofire                           0x000000010863f269 _T0Ix_IyB_TR + 41
15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e1bc2f7 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e1bd33d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e1c93a2 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1444
18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e1c8da0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 132
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010e6881ca _pthread_wqthread + 1387
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010e687c4d start_wqthread + 13
2018-03-23 15:06:48.237961-0300 OdooVendas[30310:1868520] [reports] Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication delegate]
PID: 30310, TID: 1868520, Thread name: (none), Queue name: com.apple.root.background-qos, QoS: 9
Backtrace:
4   OdooVendas                          0x00000001082d184e _T010OdooVendas15CoreDataHandlerC10getContext33_C78C41DC1F74DDA11E962327A9344CC5LLSo015NSManagedObjectG0CyFZ + 94
5   OdooVendas                          0x00000001082d1951 _T010OdooVendas15CoreDataHandlerC11saveProductys10DictionaryVySSypG1p_tFZ + 33
6   OdooVendas                          0x00000001082d588c _T010OdooVendas15CoreDataHandlerC12syncProductsyyFZys10DictionaryVySSypGcfU1_ + 60
7   OdooVendas                          0x00000001082d5aaa _T010OdooVendas15CoreDataHandlerC12syncProductsyyFZys10DictionaryVySSypGcfU1_TA + 58
8   OdooVendas                          0x00000001082f6cb1 _T010OdooVendas0A7ServiceC018getProductByIdFromA0ySi2id_ys10DictionaryVySSypGc12successBlockySSc07failureL0tFZy9Alamofire12DataResponseVy0N6XMLRPC10XMLRPCNodeVGcfU_ + 1697
9   OdooVendas                          0x00000001082f6f62 _T010OdooVendas0A7ServiceC018getProductByIdFromA0ySi2id_ys10DictionaryVySSypGc12successBlockySSc07failureL0tFZy9Alamofire12DataResponseVy0N6XMLRPC10XMLRPCNodeVGcfU_TA + 114
10  AlamofireXMLRPC                     0x00000001087e052d _T09Alamofire12DataResponseVy0A6XMLRPC10XMLRPCNodeVGIxx_AGIxi_TR + 173
11  AlamofireXMLRPC                     0x00000001087e1092 _T09Alamofire12DataResponseVy0A6XMLRPC10XMLRPCNodeVGIxx_AGIxi_TRTA + 66
12  Alamofire                           0x0000000108686819 _T09Alamofire11DataRequestC8responseACXDSo13DispatchQueueCSg5queue_x0D10SerializeryAA0B8ResponseVy16SerializedObjectQzGc17completionHandlertAA0biH8ProtocolRzlFyycfU_yycfU_ + 905
13  Alamofire                           0x000000010868f08e _T09Alamofire11DataRequestC8responseACXDSo13DispatchQueueCSg5queue_x0D10SerializeryAA0B8ResponseVy16SerializedObjectQzGc17completionHandlertAA0biH8ProtocolRzlFyycfU_yycfU_TA + 110
14  Alamofire                           0x000000010863f269 _T0Ix_IyB_TR + 41
15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e1bc2f7 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e1bd33d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e1c93a2 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1444
18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e1c8da0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 132
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010e6881ca _pthread_wqthread + 1387
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010e687c4d start_wqthread + 13
```

The curious is that all works fine but I'm fear with this message, I don't know if I making some thing wrong. I don't know working with queues in swift, but this code appears solve my problem. 
I using CoreData to manage my database.

[image]

Comment: in which line does the log occurs ? does `CoreDataHandler.saveProduct` has some UI update ? Labels, progress bars, etc ?

Comment: No, nothing of UI. Only a button to call func. I edited with image of line.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call UIKit method on background threads, so you cannot access `UIApplication.delegate` (that's a UIKit method). This is one of many reasons that you should never store global variables in the app delegate. Create a separate singleton, or pass the viewContext around where it's needed. But don't store anything in the app delegate.

That said, you also shouldn't be using a semaphore here. Semaphores are almost never the right tool. Even if you need to synchronize, you almost always should be using a DispatchGroup, not a Semaphore.

If you need to serialize the calls, then have each completion handler call the next one.

If you can do the calls in parallel, then use a DispatchGroup and use the `.notify` method on it to schedule something to do when all of them are completed. (For each network call, add a `group.enter()` and when it's completed, call `group.leave()`.)

Comment: I edited and start using DispatchGroup, but only `group.enter()` before call request, `group.leave()` on success or failure block and `group.wait()` right below request. I've created a Singleton to get the Context, but the message keeping warn me to use only on main thread, and suggests use `DispatchQueue.main.async { 
        
      }` but I don't know where write this.

Comment: "but the message keeping warn me to use only on main thread." Use what only on the main thread? Also, are you making sure to call `group.wait()` on a non-main thread? If you're blocking the main thread, you'll crash your program. Generally you want to use `group.notify()`, not `group.wait()`.

Comment: I'm with dificults to untersdant, I go create another project and make another question with other context of problem.